# Spark model fit throwing java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, machine-learning, pyspark

i have a python code for training and testing machine learning models using pyspark, the code is below:

```
def build_model(self, database_url_training, database_url_test, label):
    training_file = self.file_processor(database_url_training)
    training_file = training_file.withColumnRenamed(label, "label")

    pre_processing_text = list()
    assembler_columns_input = []

    training_string_fields = self.fields_from_dataframe(
        training_file, True)

    for column in training_string_fields:
        tokenizer = Tokenizer(
            inputCol=column, outputCol=(column + "_words"))
        pre_processing_text.append(tokenizer)

        hashing_tf_output_column_name = column + "_features"

        hashing_tf = HashingTF(
                        inputCol=tokenizer.getOutputCol(),
                        outputCol=hashing_tf_output_column_name)
        pre_processing_text.append(hashing_tf)
        assembler_columns_input.append(hashing_tf_output_column_name)

    training_number_fields = self.fields_from_dataframe(
        training_file, False)

    for column in training_number_fields:
        if(column != label):
            assembler_columns_input.append(column)

    assembler = VectorAssembler(
        inputCols=assembler_columns_input,
        outputCol="features")

    assembler.setHandleInvalid("skip")

    logistic_regression = LogisticRegression(maxIter=10)

    pipeline = Pipeline(
        stages=[*pre_processing_text, assembler, logistic_regression])
    param_grid = ParamGridBuilder().build()
    cross_validator = CrossValidator(
                        estimator=pipeline,
                        estimatorParamMaps=param_grid,
                        evaluator=BinaryClassificationEvaluator(),
                        numFolds=2)
    cross_validator_model = cross_validator.fit(training_file)

    test_file = self.file_processor(database_url_test)
    prediction = cross_validator_model.transform(test_file)

    for row in prediction.collect():
        print(row, flush=True)
```

I am using smaller datasets for the training, the training dataset:

```
PassengerId,Survived,Pclass,Name,Sex,Age,SibSp,Parch,Ticket,Fare,Cabin,Embarked
1,0,3,"Braund, Mr. Owen Harris",male,22,1,0,A/5 21171,7.25,,S
2,1,1,"Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer)",female,38,1,0,PC 17599,71.2833,C85,C
3,1,3,"Heikkinen, Miss. Laina",female,26,0,0,STON/O2. 3101282,7.925,,S
4,1,1,"Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)",female,35,1,0,113803,53.1,C123,S
5,0,3,"Allen, Mr. William Henry",male,35,0,0,373450,8.05,,S
```

The testing dataset:

```
PassengerId,Pclass,Name,Sex,Age,SibSp,Parch,Ticket,Fare,Cabin,Embarked
892,3,"Kelly, Mr. James",male,34.5,0,0,330911,7.8292,,Q
893,3,"Wilkes, Mrs. James (Ellen Needs)",female,47,1,0,363272,7,,S
894,2,"Myles, Mr. Thomas Francis",male,62,0,0,240276,9.6875,,Q
895,3,"Wirz, Mr. Albert",male,27,0,0,315154,8.6625,,S
896,3,"Hirvonen, Mrs. Alexander (Helga E Lindqvist)",female,22,1,1,3101298,12.2875,,S
```

I don't understand why this exception accusing less heap memory with this smaller dataset, in my spark cluster, i am using 3 workers, and the exception is throwed, someone can help me?

PS: i have setted spark.driver.memory from default 512 mb to 1 gb.

Comment: complete code including read of train & test data sets is needed to look into this problem effectively?

Comment: Do you think which this problem can be on dataframe reading? I am loading train and test dataframe using mongo connector, using mongo urls

Comment: Let me try loading this data and check you code.

Comment: I use mongo connector,
   file = self.spark_session.read.format("mongo").option(
            "uri", database_url).load()

Comment: database_url is the file url from internal mongo server

Comment: this files is the files which i paste in question, are .csv files with 5 rows size each

Comment: this exception is throwed in cross_validator.fit, i think which this problem is over machine larnining modeling.